# Is it possible to scrollToIndex after the cells that will be visible are rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Basically title. I want to wait for the cells that are going to visible to be rendered before scrolling to the position because right now i am getting a lot of blank area when scrolling fast.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to optimize your cell list rendering first? FlashList has this performance issue when the app renders heavier content (videos, high-resolution images,...).

Replacing  FlatList  with Shopify's FlashList should fix the problem - https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/

Comment: Hmm, never seen FlashList before, looks promising.

Comment: I tried that, and i also dug into implementation of that and tried out recyclerlistview which it is based on and i still get blank area when using scrolltoindex

Comment: I am facing this issue, the item is not getting scrolled at visible position, sometimes does. Any other solution for Flashlist for this functionality?